# Apache rewrite any uri to index.html but existing files

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, rewrite, httpd

My front-end project is based on 1 file: `frontend/index.html`

It means that every request like `/contact`, `/about`, etc should be responded by `index.html` file.

I was thought I can use these lines in my `httpd.conf` file with no any conditions:

```xml
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/frontend/"
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule . /var/www/frontend/index.html
</VirtualHost>
```

But I understood that any existing files (such as `frontend/js/app.js` or `frontend/favicon.ico` etc) will also be responded by the `index.html` while they exist in real directories.

This is what I need:

Request: `/contact` -> No `frontend/contact` file -> Response: `index.html`

Request: `/` -> No file requested -> Response: `index.html`

Request: `/js/app.js` -> `frontend/js/app.js` exists -> Response: `frontend/js/app.js`

etc.

What can I write in `httpd.conf` file in above block to do such thing?

**NOTE**: I used `VirtualHost` because I need the `back-end` files in another port (`:8080`) of server requests.

Comment: Just use "FallbackResource /index.html"

Answer (score 0):

You could add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` before the rewrite rule or just map /var/www/frontend/index.html as the 404 handler (but you need to override the 404 response with a 200).

Comment: I used `RewriteCond` clause. but nothing changed. I can map `index.html` as the 404 handler, but how can I override 404 with 200?